# Which sentence is correct

Tags: sentence-construction

My friend made a statement to which I replied

> “After 2 weeks you won't have the same say.”

Now I don't know if that sentence is correct. I think

> “After 2 weeks you will not have the same opinion.”

is more correct.

Answer (score 0):

The latter is correct. You can rephrase your first statement to be correct by saying "After two weeks, you won't feel the same way." or as you said "After 2 weeks, you will not have the same opinion."

Edit: I see what you were going for now in the first sentence. You can say instead, "After two weeks, you won't have the same opinion.".. "The same say" doesn't make sense.

Comment: The first sentence is incorrect. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Only time you can somewhat use say like that is by saying, "After two weeks, your say in this will be different." - But this has a different meaning.

Comment: "After two weeks, your say in this will be different" can be used as threat almost although that sounds weird to say. That's quite hard for me to explain. Its using say as a right to contribute to a conversation, however in the context of your sentence, this would technically work and it wouldn't be a threat. I would go with the other two options I gave though. Those are the correct ways to say the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

> "After 2 weeks you will not have the same opinion."

This sentence is more correct than the first one in your question. You can rephrase your first sentence as:

> "After 2 weeks you will not/won't have the same opinion."

The words **your say/have a say** means having the right or power to speak for oneself or on the matter in hand. Hence it does not fit in here.

However, you may even consider using some alternatives like:

> "Two weeks later, you won't be saying the same."

> "Two weeks later, you won't have the same opinion."

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence could also be interpreted very close to:

> After two weeks you won't have the same influence on the matter.

Whereas the second sentence is less ambiguous, and presumably closer to your actual intent.

Answer (score -1):

The first sentence is bad, the second one is meaningful, but probably the better solution would be

> “You don't have the same opinion as 2 weeks ago.”

or

> “Your opinion is not the same as 2 weeks ago.”

Comment: These sentences are showing past actions, the OP clearly asked about future instances.